# SQL Server 2005 error after update to windows 10

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, upgrade, windows-10

I have a SQL Server 2005 database that I can see in SQL Server Management Studio Express. There is a front end application, but since the upgrade to Windows 10, I cannot access the database with it. In SQL Server Management Studio Express there are no object folders listed for the database - and the summary shows 0 items. The database folder has a correctly named `mdf` file of 197MB.

I have very little experience of SQL Server so would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately (regarding your problem) Microsoft is pretty clear about your situation on this [SQL Server 2005 information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/general/use-sql-server-in-windows#sql-server-2005-information) doc:

> This section provides support information about instances of SQL
> Server 2005 in Windows 8.1 or Windows 8 environments. It also
> describes the options that are available for customers who are using
> SQL Server 2005.
>
> **Microsoft SQL Server 2005 (the release version and service packs) and earlier versions of SQL Server are not supported on Windows 10**,
> Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012,
> Windows 8.1, or Windows 8. You will receive a warning in the Action
> Center if Windows 10, Windows 8.1, or Windows 8 detects an instance of
> SQL Server 2005.
>
> To resolve this issue, upgrade or remove the existing instance of SQL
> Server 2005. For information about how to upgrade SQL Server, see
> [Upgrade to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Thanks for that - I don't have the SQL Server admin password.  Will I be able to upgrade without that?

Comment: @Aquamarine, in order to regain admin access you could try [Recover a lost SA password](https://www.sqlshack.com/recover-lost-sa-password/). I'd suggest creating a new admin account since changing the old one could break some application (possibly) using it.

Comment: @Aquamarine were you able to reestablish SQL Server by Upgrading it? If not, maybe you could try to follow the [Go back to Windows 8.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/go-back-to-windows-8-1-40e2d7dc-f640-b0e5-56e1-b41a27e28533) doc to revert to whatever Windows version you had before on the machine. Please, remember to mark the answer as the correct one if it has properly answered your initial question.

Comment: I installed the newer version but no luck so far.

Comment: @Aquamarine is the error the same? Do you have the logs? What version are you using now? Did you upgrade the old version or installed a new one from scratch?

Comment: I installed the new one from scratch.  Will check out error messages again tomorrow.

Comment: @Aquamarine what you have now is a different scenario from the one that generated this question (and I believe the question as to why your SQL Server stopped working after the Windows upgrade has been answered). I recommend you to open a new question adding the new problem, the error logs and the version you are using now. You can link this question if the community need to see the initial problem to properly answer your follow up question.

Comment: Thank you for your help